# numpy IndexError: too many indices for array when indexing matrix with another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix a which I create like this:

```
>>> a = np.matrix("1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12")
```

I have a matrix labels which I create like this:

```
>>> labels = np.matrix("1;0;1;1")
```

This is what the two matricies look like:

```
>>> a
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]])
>>> labels
matrix([[1],
        [0],
        [1],
        [1]])
```

As you can see, when I select all columns, there is no problem

```
>>> a[labels == 1, :]
matrix([[ 1,  7, 10]])
```

But when I try to specify a column I get an error

```
>>> a[labels == 1, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 305, in     __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
IndexError: too many indices for array
>>>
```

Does anybody know why this is?
I am aware there are similar questions to this already but none of them explain my problem well enough, neither are the answers helpful to me.

Comment: labels is 2-d, but the index uses it as if it was 1-d.

Comment: Actually, the first indexing is wrong too, with numpy >=1.8. you will get the same error there too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `labels` is a matrix when you do `labels==1` you obtain a boolean matrix of the same shape. Then doing `a[labels==1, :]` will return you **only** the first column with the lines corresponding to the match. Note that your intention to get:

```
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]])
```

was not achieved (you got only the first column), even though it worked for NumPy < 1.8 (as pointed out by @seberg).

In order to get what you want you can use a flattened view of `labels`:

```
a[labels.view(np.ndarray).ravel()==1, :]
```

Comment: Nice, I find 2D arrays better behaved for most np work.  With a matlab background a lot of people default to using matrix vs array. BTW: I get the same behavior in 1.7.

Comment: labels.view(np.ndarray) changes the type of `labels` to np.ndarray while the `ravel` call flattens the array. Note `==1` can be ommited