# unumpy.uarray -- IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, arrays

```
hdudata = pf.open(p_new)
tbdata = hdudata[1].data
hdudata.close()

MGII = unumpy.uarray(tbdata['LOGL_BROAD_MGII'],abs(tbdata['LOGL_BROAD_MGII_ERR']))

lum = unumpy.uarray(1.0 , 1.0)

for i in range (len(tbdata)):
    if (tbdata['LOGL_BROAD_MGII'][i] != 0.0):
        a = unumpy.nominal_values(unumpy.pow(10 , MGII[i])/34.0) 
        b = unumpy.std_devs(unumpy.pow(10 , MGII[i])/34.0)
        lum[i] =+ ufloat(a[0] , b[0])
        print 'MGII'
        print unumpy.pow(10 , MGII[i])/34.0        
        print lum[i]
```

I get that error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Denny\Documents\Denny\Unimib\Tesina_triennale\Programma_fit\Fit_lin_log.py in <module>()
     72         a = unumpy.nominal_values(unumpy.pow(10 , MGII[i])/34.0)
     73         b = unumpy.std_devs(unumpy.pow(10 , MGII[i])/34.0)
---> 74         lum[i] =+ ufloat(a[0] , b[0])
     75         print 'MGII'
     76         print unumpy.pow(10 , MGII[i])/34.0

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I inserted a lot of print for studies the problem.
The function of unumpy give a array type object.

Comment: I think your error comes from numpy array , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165565/numpy-indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array-when-indexing-matrix-with-another

Comment: thank you! I have just seen thar page and it didn't help me. I have tried to call that array from terminal and I find a very strange thing: When i call a, I find: a Out[18]: array(1.350157920123701e+42)
I thought that is very strange an output array without the braces  [ ] , si I tried to call some argument of a.
And i find that it is an 'unsized object'
I never listen about that kind of array and I can find information about it on the web.
Do you know something?